# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object when using httplib2 with link

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am unsure about this error I am getting.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\MICHAEL\Desktop\Project X\dataprod.py", line 30, in 
>       status, response = http.request(quote_page)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\httplib2__init__.py", line 1368, in request
>       (scheme, authority, request_uri, defrag_uri) = urlnorm(uri)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\httplib2__init__.py", line 175, in urlnorm
>       (scheme, authority, path, query, fragment) = parse_uri(uri)
>
> File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\httplib2__init__.py", line 171, in parse_uri
>       groups = URI.match(uri).group
>
> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

My code is below, could this be a permissions error? I am still new to coding and my apologies with this is a rookie error and for my appalling code. Basically trying to find links with in the page I am scraping.

```
import shelve

f = open("data.txt", 'w')
print("...")

from urllib.request import urlopen

from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import httplib2

quote_page = ['https://www.auspost.com']

#ERROR BELOW

http = httplib2.Http()
status, response = http.request(quote_page)

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print(link['href'])

info = []
for pg in quote_page:

    page = urlopen(pg)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    name_box = soup.find('html')

    name = name_box.text.strip()

    info.append((name))

    print("PULLED DATA")

import csv
from datetime import datetime

with open("index.csv", 'a', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)

    for name in info:
        writer.writerow([name])
f.write(name)
print(f, name)


Exit=input("Press '1' to save and close: ")

if Exit == 1:
    f.close()
    exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just having it as `quote_page = 'https://www.auspost.com'` instead of in brackets.

Edit:
Try changing this:

```
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        print(link['href'])    
info = []
for pg in quote_page:

    page = urlopen(pg)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    name_box = soup.find('html')

    name = name_box.text.strip()

    info.append((name))

    print("PULLED DATA")
```

to:

```
quotes = []
for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_attr('href'):
        quotes.append(link['href'])

info = []
for pg in quotes:

    page = urlopen(pg)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    name_box = soup.find('html')

    name = name_box.text.strip()

    info.append((name))

    print("PULLED DATA")`
```

Comment: Cheers that fixed the problem, but I have come across another. Any ideas as to what this is?   https://pastebin.com/s8rrQRzC

Comment: That is popping up as a result of `for pg in quote_page:`.

quote_page is a string so it is iterating each character. Maybe my first solution was not the best for your problem. Can you explain the intention `for pg in quote_page:` ?

Comment: Being new to all this, I was blindly following a tutorial for that part. If there is a better way to do that part I am all ears. Basically the whole program is aimed at scraping the entire html format from a website and then finding any links within the website and saving them in a separate file. Hope that helps?

Comment: Can you double check that you changed `for pg in quote_page:` to `for pg in quotes:`

Comment: Hmm i did make that error and have changed the code yet I still get an error. https://pastebin.com/HeUjJ0cp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169076/discussion-between-corecreatives-and-michael-c).